# How can do exception handling without using Fault Contract in WCF

Tags: wcf

I have handled exception in wcf using Fault Contract but interviewer asked Can we do exception handling in WCF without using the FaultContract? If Yes then how?

Comment: Please give us some more information so we can help you.

Comment: In WCF,  we exposed the SOAP Exception to the client using Fault Contract which is in readable format(Client can understand what exception is coming into the service)
but can we achieve the same without using fault Contract

Comment: Please update your answer(with the content of your comment) so it's more easy to understand for someone who can help you. (click "Edit" under your question)

Comment: Usually you get internal server error code 500 but not more than that. There is includeexceptiondetailsinfault switch which tells client something has gone wrong at the service with details.There are many ways to skin a cat. Say for example your service write exception details to some kind of database log and as a part of return data contract you send ID of that error log and then your client can make another call to the service to get the details passing that ID to say method called GetErrorDetails(int ID).

Comment: Thanks Hakunamatata.   I had given the same answer to the interviewer "set includeexceptiondetailsinfault  is True in web.config file but he is not satisfied with the answer. Please help me out if their is another way to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

MyException fault = new MyException("Error message");
   throw new FaultException(fault, new FaultReason("Reason Text"));

Comment: Lalit r u sure this the right answer.... because interviewer asked me question "How can do exception handling without using Fault Contract in WCF"

Comment: Hey vhangout Check it                           http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pedram/archive/2008/01/25/wcf-error-handling-and-some-best-practices.aspx